# Removing a nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

```
package com.example.first666;

import com.example.first666.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 * 
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
                HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(
                mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    public void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

nullpointerexception occurs when processing `display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);` which crashes the app saying 'unfortunately the app has stopped'. How do I fix NullPointerException?

Here's the XML file as requested. Any help appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textSize="200sp" 
         android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="500sp"
    android:layout_height="200sp"
    android:text="@string/Add"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="75sp"
     android:id="@+id/bAdd"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="500sp"
    android:layout_height="200sp"
    android:text="@string/Sub"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="75sp"
     android:id="@+id/bSub"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the LogCat as requested

```
06-05 14:52:46.269: E/Trace(466): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-05 14:52:48.300: D/AndroidRuntime(466): Shutting down VM
06-05 14:52:48.309: W/dalvikvm(466): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.first666/com.example.first666.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at com.example.first666.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:62)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-05 14:52:48.360: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  ... 11 more
06-05 14:53:28.219: I/Process(466): Sending signal. PID: 466 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you show your xml file ?

Comment: and post your logcat output

Comment: it can not crashes  display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

Comment: Do you have a TExtView called tvDisplay in your layout xml called activity_fullscreen?

Comment: Yup. You can check yourself. I have posted the XML too.

Answer (score 1):

```
final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
```

does not belongs to the current view hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

If line 62 is `add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ...`

Then check if this line is returning `null`:

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
```

Comment: @Judas What do you mean by "No"? Then what is at line 62??